# How can I deploy a client-side ReactJS + Node.js application on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, express, reactjs

I have a client-side ReactJS and Node.js Express application running on the local machine at the moment. I would like to now deploy the client-side application to an Ubuntu Linux server, where the back-end, database and REST API, is already running.

What's the way to go about doing so? I did the research but all seem to have both front-end and back-end, and do not fit the criteria that I am looking for. So I was lost and reached out here. Thank you

Comment: Please be more specific on what you are trying to do.  Client you mean is the consumer of the API that runs on express?

Comment: No actually I have a server and client under one project with MERN stack, and an Ubuntu Linux server running. How do I deploy it on there? Do I simply install all the dependencies and start the server just like how I would locally?

Comment: Yes you can or you could use PM2.  http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/